# how to retrieve some preference like keyboard repeat rate on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash

As the title I said, for now, I need this info on my local Mac machine, I googled and found a unique answer which is using 'xset q' command, but that is a third-party tool, do we have some native command or Mac bash function to retrieve these info?

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in `standardUserDefaults`, in the `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` file.

I don't write much Objective-C, but I believe this is how you would access it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"KeyRepeat"]
```

A larger value means a longer delay, and the range you can set in System Preferences appears to be `120` - `2`. When set to off, `InitialKeyRepeat` becomes the much-larger `300000`.

Comment: I checked what you mentioned, it really exist there, so I have another question, where can I find all the values I want to have, I looked at the NSUserDefaults on Apple guide, but I can't find KeyRepeat, also I need other info about keyboard, like layout of keyboard etc.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure if they are documented anywhere, but you might try inspecting the plist directly, `cp ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist ~/Documents/GlobalPreferences.plist ; plutil -convert xml1 ~/Documents/GlobalPreferences.plist` Then you can open the `GlobalPreferences.plist` in your Documents directory in a text editor.

Comment: I checked this plist as you said, I saw some info I need, but I don't notice some other info like auto layout of keyboard, thanks for your help. If you know more, that'll be great!